# DELETE Trigger for Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am creating two triggers. One to catch the inserted values for the Rewards table and one to catch the deleted values for the Rewards table. The triggers main function is to record what type of change was made into the the audit table.

Rewards Table: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEGNr.png)

Audit Table: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M670m.png)

The SQL for the audit_insert_trigger is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_rewards_insert 
ON Rewards AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS IF UPDATE(category)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @category   char(6)
    DECLARE @type_change    char(20)

    SELECT @category = (SELECT category FROM inserted)  

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @type_change = 'Inserted'
        END 
    INSERT INTO audit_rewards
        VALUES (
        @category, USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), @type_change)
END 

CREATE TRIGGER tr_rewards_delete
ON Rewards AFTER UPDATE 
AS IF UPDATE(category)
BEGIN
DECLARE @category   char(6)
DECLARE @type_change    char(20)

SELECT @category = (SELECT category FROM deleted)   

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @type_change = 'Deleted'
    END 

INSERT INTO audit_rewards
    VALUES (
    @category, USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), @type_change)
 END
```

My idea was to just replace where "inserted" was and put "deleted". I'm not really understanding 1. the logic as to why that will not work and 2. How to get the deleted values into the audit table and record that it was a delete.

Cannot make it in one trigger. Must be two independent triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_rewards_insert 
ON Rewards AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS IF UPDATE(category)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @category   char(2)
    DECLARE @type_change    char(20)
    SELECT @category = (SELECT category FROM inserted)  
    SELECT @type_change = 'Inserted'

    INSERT INTO audit_rewards
    VALUES (@category, USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), @type_change)
    END
CREATE TRIGGER tr_rewards_delete
ON Rewards AFTER DELETE, UPDATE 
    AS IF UPDATE(category)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @category   char(2)
    DECLARE @type_change    char(20)

    SELECT @category = (SELECT category FROM deleted)   
    SELECT @type_change = 

    INSERT INTO audit_rewards
    VALUES (@category, USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), @type_change)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` trigger is incorrect.  I think it should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_rewards_insert 
ON Rewards AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS IF UPDATE(category)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit_rewards
        SELECT 'INSERTED, USER_NAME(), GETDATE(), category
        FROM inserted;
END;
```

The `DELETED` trigger would basically be the same.  Never assume that `inserted` and `deleted` have only a single row.

Comment: The insert works fine and logs in the audit table. The delete is the trigger that will not log to the table.

Comment: Both triggers will fail for a statement that affects multiple rows.  "Never assume that inserted and deleted have only a single row."

Comment: Nevermind my comment. I see what you are talking about now. It will not log multiple entries at once. Still new to SQL!!